In redis, how to quickly get names based on a list of keys
I want to implement a tag cloud.
Tag information is stored in Redis:
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(tagKey, tagName);

The usage count of the tags is also stored in Redis, using a sorted set:
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().incrementScore(TAG_CLOUD_KEY, tagKey, 1);

My question is that when showing the tag cloud, I want to show the tagName. However, when retrieving the tag usage count via TAG_CLOUD_KEY, I can only get the tagKey. How can I match tagKeys with ralative tagNames, how can I design the storage structure in Redis to meet this requirement?
I don't want to loop through all the tag keys to get the tagName via the tagKey, as this seems very inefficient. What is the best practice in Redis for such key-name matching problem?

Could you restructure your data so that you are storing the tag in the Sorted Set instead of the key that references the tag? If so, you could just call .rangeWithScores instead and have everything you need in a single call.

I have considered this implementation, but it would be difficult to maintain if the tag names need to be modified.

What if you store the tag keys and tag names in a Hash? The field in the Hash could be the tag keys. Query the Sorted Set, then query the Hash for the specific fields you want using whatever the Spring Data Redis function is that maps to HMGET. Net total of two Redis commands although you would need to match things up in your code.
